# I cannot use badges and labels in my website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to include some badges and labels in my website like the ones in
[this site](https://concisecss.com/archive/v2.0.0/add-ons/badges-labels/)

The problem is that in my case they doesn't work and I don't know why.

I made a really simple index page and a style.css just to test it out. The .css file works somehow because i changed the background color of the entire index.html and it works fine. But the labels are all grey and not showing colors as they should.

This is my index.html page.

```css
.label,
.badge {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

.badge {
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 7px;
}

.label[href]:hover, .label[href]:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.badge:hover, a.badge:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.label a,
.badge a {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.label:empty,
.badge:empty {
  display: none;
}
a body {background-color: coral;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    asdadadsa
    <span class="label">Default Label</span>
<span class="label bg-gray">Gray Label</span>
<span class="label bg-green">Green Label</span>
<span class="label bg-blue">Blue Label</span>
<span class="label bg-yellow">Yellow Label</span>
<span class="label bg-red">Red Label</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The .css page is exactly how it is in [this page](https://concisecss.com/archive/v2.0.0/downloads/objects/badges-labels/badges.css) + a 
`body {background-color: coral;}` just to test it out if it works.

This is how they are showed to me:

[image]

Do you know what it could be?

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz or something similar für us to test?

Comment: A stacksnippet is better. No need to leave the site

Comment: You need to import the style sheet for the Twitter bootstrap. There's likely also a javascript file you need to import as well. As far as I can tell you we're not doing that. Of course your example maybe missing it.

Comment: The have all the .bg- in this file : `https://concisecss.com/archive/v2.0.0/css/concise.min.css`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: this happened because you never included the CSS from Concise in your page. Please check before asking  such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the bg-* classes bg-green and so on.
In your stylesheet you need to add something like

```
.bg-green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

This approach s ok if you don’t intend to use the complete twitter bootstrap. Then you need to import the complete css, but its best to use sass.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23975444)

Comment: But the bg-* classes is missing in the stylesheet. That is why the badges is not showing. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file misses somes classes like bg-yellow or bg-gray, you should create them or use the CDN of Concise